# Nginx server doesnt write access logs

Tags: nginx

I am having a weird problem on my server.
Every access.log - error.log per domain works but the main access.log for all sites on /var/log/nginx/access.log doesnt work at all (the error.log does work)
I have tried deleting it and restart nginx it does create the logs but it doesnt change it 
Here is my nginx config

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}
http {
    log_format upstream_time '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                             '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                             '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'
                             'rt=$request_time uct="$upstream_connect_time" uht="$upstream_header_time" urt="$upstream_response_time"';
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
    more_clear_headers Server;
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstream_time;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
}
```

ls -l /var/log/

```
total 114336
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root              481 Apr  6 01:16 alternatives.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root             3004 Mar 31 14:36 alternatives.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root             1679 Feb 24 03:53 alternatives.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root             3431 Jan 25 18:44 alternatives.log.3.gz
drwxr-x--- 2 root     adm              4096 Jan 19 06:25 apache2
-rw-r----- 1 root     adm                 0 Mar 11 06:25 apport.log
-rw-r----- 1 root     adm              1103 Mar 10 21:27 apport.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 root     adm               272 Feb 17 19:15 apport.log.2.gz
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root             4096 Apr  1 06:25 apt
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm          11092121 Apr 10 11:39 auth.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm          63598571 Apr  9 06:25 auth.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm           3094301 Apr  2 06:25 auth.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm           2099363 Mar 26 06:25 auth.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm           3433467 Mar 20 06:25 auth.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root                0 Apr 10 11:00 bandwidth
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root            57457 Jul 19  2016 bootstrap.log
-rw------- 1 root     utmp              384 Apr  7 10:36 btmp
-rw------- 1 root     utmp           933888 Mar 18 13:36 btmp.1
drwxr-xr-x 2 clamav   clamav           4096 Apr  9 06:25 clamav
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root             4096 Apr 26  2016 dist-upgrade
-rw-r----- 1 root     adm                31 Jul 19  2016 dmesg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root            41011 Apr 10 08:15 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root           227634 Mar 31 14:36 dpkg.log.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root            21382 Feb 28 21:52 dpkg.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root            58764 Jan 27 15:10 dpkg.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root            32032 Mar 10 16:36 faillog
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root              588 Feb 21 17:07 fontconfig.log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root             4096 Jan 17 22:06 fsck
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root             4096 Jan 17 22:17 installer
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm           1113870 Apr 10 11:39 kern.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm           7790596 Apr  9 06:23 kern.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            998131 Apr  2 06:25 kern.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            663229 Mar 26 06:24 kern.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm           3932240 Mar 20 06:24 kern.log.4.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     utmp           292292 Apr  7 10:36 lastlog
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root             4096 Jun 30  2016 lxd
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm                 0 Feb  6 06:25 mail.err
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm               105 Feb  3 10:24 mail.err.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm               785 Jan 27 00:55 mail.err.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm               751 Jan 21 19:58 mail.err.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm              8476 Apr 10 09:47 mail.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            290793 Apr  9 00:00 mail.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm             55658 Apr  2 00:00 mail.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm             30300 Mar 26 06:22 mail.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm             23429 Mar 20 00:00 mail.log.4.gz
drwxrws--- 2 root     list             4096 Apr  9 06:25 mailman
drwxr-xr-x 2 mongodb  debian-spamd     4096 Apr  9 06:25 mongodb
drwxr-x--- 2 mysql    adm              4096 Apr 10 06:25 mysql
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data         4096 Apr  9 06:25 nginx
drwxrwxr-t 2 root     postgres         4096 Jan 22 06:25 postgresql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root              372 Apr 10 06:57 procmail.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root              306 Apr 10 00:00 procmail.log.1.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root              307 Apr  9 00:00 procmail.log.2.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root              310 Apr  8 00:00 procmail.log.3.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root              309 Apr  7 00:00 procmail.log.4.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root              310 Apr  6 00:00 procmail.log.5.gz
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root             4096 Apr  9 06:25 proftpd
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            645606 Apr 10 11:39 syslog
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm           3262359 Apr 10 06:25 syslog.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            261921 Apr  9 06:25 syslog.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            286213 Apr  8 06:25 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            321555 Apr  7 06:25 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            321139 Apr  6 06:25 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            291409 Apr  5 06:25 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            318186 Apr  4 06:25 syslog.7.gz
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root             4096 May 12  2016 sysstat
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm           1043651 Apr 10 11:39 ufw.log
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm           6978511 Apr  9 06:23 ufw.log.1
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            831489 Apr  2 06:25 ufw.log.2.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            559149 Mar 26 06:24 ufw.log.3.gz
-rw-r----- 1 syslog   adm            864901 Mar 20 06:24 ufw.log.4.gz
drwxr-x--- 2 root     adm              4096 Apr  1 06:25 unattended-upgrades
drwx--x--x 2 root     root             4096 Apr  9 06:25 virtualmin
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     utmp             8832 Apr  7 17:38 wtmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root     utmp            42624 Mar 30 10:24 wtmp.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root          1145316 Feb  5 15:40 xferlog
```

ls -l /var/log/nginx/

```
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root   0 Apr  7 14:01 access.log
-rw-r----- 1 www-data adm    0 Apr  9 06:25 error.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root 395 Apr  9 06:25 error.log.1
```

When nginx creates files  they both have -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root
when nginx adds info the file premissions are changing to -rw-r----- 1 www-data adm

Comment: have you checked the permissions on your log folders? and/or journal to see if nginx is having issues writing or creating files?
(having to post instead of comment. sorry)

Comment: yes i did. The error log works great (they both have the same premissions and owner)

Comment: Please edit your question to add ALL the following 1) The server block(s) for the sites that aren't working 2) "ls -l /var/log/" 3) "ls -l /var/log/nginx" 4) The results of changing your access_log statement to "access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined". If #4 fails because "combined" isn't defined you can copy it from it from this page http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html   . My first theory is permissions, my second is that your access log format has an error. Please tag me @tim when you've done this if you want me to have another look.

Comment: @Tim thanks for your answer 1)the logs from every site are working just fine 2-3) both are in the question now 4) the site logs with main(my custom format)works i was using combined at the start both are working just fine but not on /var/log/nginx/access.log tho i also tried to make it readable and writable for every user still doesnt work

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. If your sites all have working access logs, what are you expecting to see in the main access log? Each hit goes to one log. Are all your servers using that "upstream_time" log format? Perhaps you could add one server block with location and such, remove anything sensitive.

Comment: i wanted to make the /var/log/nginx/access.log to contain all the access logs from all the sites there and on another server i already done it so am not sure what i did wrong on this one...

Comment: okay. start `nginx` as `root` user or with `sudo privileges` and give a try?

Comment: thanks for you answer but i am starting - restarting the service from root already.

Comment: Well since i couldn't fix it i used goaccess to get the same results and somewhat organized here is the command that i used
`zcat -f /var/log/virtualmin/*access_log* | goaccess -`